# Making a curved tube thinner or thicker without scaling its overall size

Tags: modeling

Is there a simple way to change the thickness/diameter of a curved tube without scaling its overall size?
E.g. scaling the minor radius of an already created torus without affecting its major radius or change the bevel width of a curve that has already been converted to a mesh.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, in edit mode you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale along vertex normals instead of from the median point.

So you can scale this...
[image]

To this...
[image]

To this...
[image]

This also works for bezier curves as well, even without converting to mesh.

Comment: Wow, that is such a useful feature!

Comment: This isn't working as pictured here for me. Alt + S tends to want to scale a torus into an eye shape.

Comment: @user2867288  Make sure your pivot point is not set to 3D cursor or something like that.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is the shrinken/flatten tool you can find in the sidebar, too.

Answer (score 5):

**FYI:**  in more-recent versions of Blender, suggestion #1 is simply available by a *"Shrink/Fatten"* button on the tool pane when in Edit mode.  (It is equivalent to `Alt+S`, as it indicates.)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following method.

1. Change [Mesh Select Mode to Edge](http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html)
2. Select [Edge Ring](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges_faces.html#edge-rings)
3. Select [Edge Loop](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges_faces.html#edge-loops)
4. Change [Pivot Point to Individual origins](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/individual_origins.html)
5. Scale

This may seem a rather tedeous procedure, but can be used on tube with ends.

Let's go through this on the mesh below.

[image: Before]

## 1. Change [Mesh Select Mode to Edge](http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html)

Aim: To select edge loops individually.

hotkeys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> -> <kbd>E</kbd>
[image: SelectMode]

## 2. Select [Edge Ring](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges_faces.html#edge-rings)

Aim: Select one edge for each edge loops.

Hotkeys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd> on one of the edges

[image: EdgeRing]

## 3. Select [Edge Loop](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges_faces.html#edge-loops)

Aim: Select all edge loops.

Hotkeys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> -> <kbd>P</kbd>

Caution: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd> is usually used for edge loop select but cannot be for this method.

[image: EdgeLoop]
[image: EdgeLoop]

## 4. Change [Pivot Point to Individual orignis](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/individual_origins.html)

Aim: Manipulate each edge loop individually.

Hotkeys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Period</kbd>

[image: IndivPivot]

## 5. Scale

Aim: Change Size

hotkeys: <kbd>S</kbd>

[image: Scale]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the solidify modifier(Modifiers tab>Add Modifiers>Solidify)
Adjust the thickness.

If you have a limited poly count just delete the internal mesh.